# How do I get sound output from a MIDI keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, jack, midi

I'm running Arch, and I want to run my AKAI MPK mini mk II through Qsynth.  I have gotten to the point where, when I press a key on the keyboard, Qsynth acknowledges it, however it makes no sound.  Qsynth does have a soundfont installed (I've tried several, currently FluidR3_GM.sf2), and from qjackctl I can see that the keyboard is connected to the FLUID synth's input, and qsynth's outputs are connected to the system inputs.  But no sound.

Edit as of 08-Mar-2022:  It just works now.  A couple of days ago, I decided to try again.  I opened Qsynth, tried to connect the keyboard to it, was told it was already connected, and then I pressed a key and it made sound.  I have no idea what changed; perhaps something updated, and that's all.